# Boost Asio PubSub Model: No publishing of Data

Tags: c++, boost, publish-subscribe

I am trying to make a pub-sub model using the boost Asio. I am using Boost 1.65.0 on Ubuntu 18.0.

I created a client model for publishing data and server for subscribing data.

I was successful in creating the connection between the both but when trying to publish data, no data is being send

I have referred to the given link for building the pub/sub model as I am very new to this subject.
https://github.com/di9it/msghub

Client Code:

```
int main()
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        msghub msghub(io_service);
        msghub.connect("localhost", 1334);
        msghub.publish("Publish", "new message");
        io_service.run();
    }
```

Server Code:

```
void on_message(const std::string& topic, std::vector<char>& message)
    {
       // handle message
    }

    int main()
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        // Create hub to listen on 0xbee port
        msghub msghub(io_service);
        msghub.create(1334);
        // Subscribe on "any topic"
        msghub.subscribe("Publish", on_message);
        // Current or any another client
        //msghub.publish("Publish", "hello");
        io_service.run();
    }
```

Please, help me with solution.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the quality of that project, compiling it results in a lot of worrying warnings¹, and stuff like this:

```
    // TODO: Handle IO error - on thread exit
    int e = error.value();
```

So, I tried it out for you. Turns out the server immediately segfaults. Using `-fsanitize=undefined,address` learns:

> `/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/msghub/src/hubconnection.cpp:55:6: runtime error: execution reached the end of a value-returning function without returning a value`

That's... not a good sign? Added a judicious `return true;` and continued. Debugging through the client code, I found

```
bool msghub_impl::publish(const std::string& topic, const std::vector<char>& message)
{
    if (!initok_)
        return false;

    hubmessage msg;
    msg.set_message(topic, message);
    msg.set_action(hubmessage::action::publish);
    publisher_->write(msg);

    return true;
}
```

I see `publisher_->write(msg)` posts `do_write` to the io_service. Apparently that does *not* execute. The usual reason is when `run()` has already returned, so the service is "done". Sprinkling some asserts show that `msghub.connect` causes this... premature "jaculation" of the service:

```
    msghub.connect("localhost", 1334);
    assert(!io_service.stopped());
```

This assert fails. Before that point it passes. What you would really expect is

- for the `msghub` to either

  - **not touch the service controls** (it doesn't OWN the service anyway)
  - or **put some artificial `work` on it**

We can do the latter in our code, but we have to watch closely to remove it in time or the service would *never* complete:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <msghub.h>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
    {
        msghub msghub(io_service);

        msghub.connect("localhost", 1334);
        assert(!io_service.stopped()); // no longer fails due to `work`

        //msghub.subscribe("Publish", [](std::string, std::vector<char>){});
        msghub.publish("Publish", "new message");
        io_service.run_for(1s);
    }
    io_service.run();
}
```

This works:

[image]

> ### Another Workaround
>
> As a dirty workaround, you **could** subscribe:
>
> ```
> auto donothing = [](std::string const&, std::vector<char> const&){};  msghub.subscribe("Publish", donothing);
> ```
>
> This is ugly, but it has a similar effect to creating `work`. Note
> that indeed it will also prevent the service from ever completing
> spontaneously.

---

¹ `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: I made pull request at the project addressing all of the issues (yours and three others I created). You might want to give it a look https://github.com/di9it/msghub/pull/5

Comment: I ended up forking and cleaning up the interface, getting up-to-date with Boost 1.75, c++17, improving perf and correcting error-handling/reporting. I [offered](https://github.com/di9it/msghub/pull/6) my work back to the repo but you can find [the fork here](https://github.com/sehe/msghub).